# Strategies for dealing with Persistent Store load failure

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nspersistentstore

The default strategy in the Apple sample code for dealing with any error in loading a persistent store is to log an error and bail. There's always an explanation (in a comment) that you should really do something more user friendly:

```
NSError *error = nil;
persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc]
        initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                              configuration:nil
                                                        URL:storeURL
                                                    options:nil
                                                      error:&error]) {
// Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
abort();
}
```

Is there any sample code for a better way to deal with a failure to load the persistent store? Does anyone have a suggestion on a better strategy than just logging an error?

Would it be better to archive the old store, then give the user back a fresh store (with a message to say what had happened)